# 1С Документооборот. Не получается работать с файлами в тонком клиенте через веб-соединение

Tags: 1с, iis

При запуске базы предлагает только авторизацию 1С, а авторизацию на сервере не спрашивает, но при попытке сохранить файл в базу, выскакивает окно для ввода логина и пароля на сервере:

[image: окно авторизации]

и пароль виндовс не подходит.

Конфигурация:

Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2 Enterprise x64 Edition SP2

IIS 6

1С:Предприятие 8.3 (8.3.8.2027) Клиент-серверный вариант.

Тонкий клиент. Подключение через строку Веб-соединения: Srvr="*****";Ref="***";

Помогите победить, пожалуйста.

Comment: Какие проблемы с правами доступа

Comment: на сервере какой вариант авторизации в настройках, Windows или Server? Какая СУБД?

Comment: Разобрались. Оказывается если снаружи указан нестандартный порт, который перенаправляется на внутренний сервер1С, то публикация базы на внутреннем сервере IIS должна осуществляться в порт с таким-же номером, какой указан снаружи. Неочевидненькая вещь.